# Rails: return cloned object plus one more attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, append

An object results in following JSON response:

```
[{
  "email":"admin@host.com",
  "id":2,
  "role_id":2,
}]
```

I want to add a custom `is_admin` attribute:

```
[{
  "email":"admin@host.com",
  "id":2,
  "is_admin":"true",
  "role_id":2,
}]
```

I would like to inject the "is_admin" flag in a smart way:

```
full_obj = user.do_something_to_add_attribute('is_admin', user.is_admin?)
```

so that the original `user` object will not be modified, but only the result of `do_something_to_add_attribute` will contain the new flag. How to do this?

Comment: Why not just copy the user object?

Comment: How to copy the right way without doing this attribute-by-attribute?

Comment: What is the class of user object?

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: If I understand you right you have an object User which you are sending somewhere in the form of JSON and you want that JSON to contain extra field 'is_admin' which does not belong to user. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, if you need `full_obj` to be a kind of User and act like it, you better just expand the User model. But I don't actually see the need in `is_admin` flag when your user already does respond to a `is_admin?` method.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `to_json`, try

```
# user.rb
def is_admin
  is_admin?
end

# in generating the json object
user.to_json(only: [:email, :id, :role_id], methods: [:is_admin])
```

Comment: I suppose that I can't convert explicitly to JSON in an inherited method. It returned an User object and should keep doing so.